# Undefined URL Helper Method for Anonymous Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I ran a scaffold command for rails and have been unable to get the specs working for the views. They always fail when a URL helper method is called saying something such as:

```
  1) engine/foo/bar/index renders a list of foo/bar
 Failure/Error: <td><%= link_to 'Show', foo_bar %></td>

 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `foo_bar_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fed161bf908>:0x007fed13d25750>
```

I've attempted including the URL helpers in the spec, but that gives me another error.

I've checked out https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/476 and tried the solutions posted there with no help. I've tried multiple other solutions posted with no dice. In all I haven't been able to figure out why or how to fix this failure. I'm using ruby version 2.3.0, rails version 4.2.7.1, rspec-core 3.6.0, and rails-rspec 3.6.1.

My project directory for the views looks like this:

```
Project
  app
   views
     engine
       foo
         bars
           index.html.erb
  spec
    views
      engine
        foo
          bars
            index.html.erb_spec.rb
```

My index.html.erb file looks like this:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Foo Bars</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Displays</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @foo_bars.each do |foo_bar| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= foo_bar.display %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', foo_bar %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_foo_bar_path(foo_bar) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', foo_bar, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Bar', new_foo_bar_path %>
```

The spec for the above file is:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'engine/foo/bars/index', type: :view do

  before(:each) do
    assign(:foo_bars, [
      Engine::Foo::Bar.create!(display: 'Display'),
      Engine::Foo::Bar.create!(display: 'Display')
    ])
  end

  it 'renders a list of foo/bars' do
    render
    assert_select 'tr>td', text: 'Display'.to_s, :count => 2
  end
end
```

My routes.rb is:

```
Engine::Engine.routes.draw do

  namespace :foo do
    resources :bars
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to have `foo_bar_path(foo_bar)` on `<td><%= link_to 'Show', foo_bar %></td>`

Comment: Please attach `rake routes` output, it should be helpful for debugging.

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin I won't be able to run rake routes or rails routes because it's an engine. However, I have attached my routes.rb file. Hopefully that'll suffice

Comment: It *looks* like you're in process of developing an engine. If so, it seems like you're making things extra-hard on yourself. The file structure seems unconventional. Naming your engine `Engine` seems like it might cause eventual problems. You're not testing in a conventional `spec/dummy` way. I could be wrong, so apologies in advance. Just some observations.

Comment: @jvillian The name of the engine is not engine. I simply changed it to make the files a little more generalized. :)